Did the children of Israel already have the entire Law when the instructions of fringes were given?

[Num 15:37-41 KJV] 37 And the LORD spake unto Moses, saying, 38 Speak
unto the children of Israel, and bid them that they make them fringes
in the borders of their garments throughout their generations, and
that they put upon the fringe of the borders a ribband of blue: 39 And
it shall be unto you for a fringe, that ye may look upon it, and
remember all the commandments of the LORD, and do them; and that ye
seek not after your own heart and your own eyes, after which ye use to
go a whoring: 40 That ye may remember, and do all my commandments, and
be holy unto your God. 41 I [am] the LORD your God, which brought you
out of the land of Egypt, to be your God: I [am] the LORD your God.


Some of the law was known before Sinai, but many ceremonial practices were given first in Leviticus and Numbers.  How much was known is debated so we do not know for sure.  However, it is clear that the Noahide Law and the 10 commandments were known well before Sinai.

Question StatedAs stated, the question doesn't seem to be referring to "previous occurrences of some of the laws in previous cultures", but whether the whole Mosaic Law was in tact at the time the "Fringe requirement" was ordered. Was all "the revealed law" all given to Israel by then? As such, this is a different question than the one referred to in the comment.
